# Get the next element of an Anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I change the value of the next element(td) by searching anchor tag

I have this html code

```
<TR>
<TD>
   <DIV align=center>4</DIV>
</TD>
<TD>
    <DIV align=left>
        <A href="sample.asp?list=1&amp;vote=1">Juan Dela Cruz</A>
    </DIV>
</TD>
<TD>25</TD>
</TR>
```

and I have this javascript

```
<SCRIPT>
    setTimeout(function() {
        var searchString = 'Juan Dela Cruz';
        var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
            if (elements[i].innerHTML.indexOf(searchString) !== -1)
               elements[i].nextSibling.innerHTML = getRandomInt(200,250);
    }, 200);


    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
</SCRIPT>
```

Then, I want to search thru list of anchors(a) tag with name 'Juan Dela Cruz' .. Then use it to get its next element .. so that I can change the value 25 inside td tag

Searching anchor tag with that name works perfectly , I only have a problem in getting the next element...
I got an error in .nextSibling .. can someone help me fix this code?? thanks :)

Comment: u can get the current **td** of that with the name with **parents('td')** and get the next td using **next()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this snippets:

Main thing is you need to care about `closest()` to get the next `td` sibling. This `closest("td")` will return your nearest parent `td` element. From there you can get your next `td` element using `next("td")`.

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/j8e6cnh0/)

```js
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var searchString = 'Juan Dela Cruz';
    $("a").each(function() {
      if ($(this).text() == searchString) {
        $(this).closest("td").next("td")[0].innerHTML = getRandomInt(200, 250);
      }
    })
  }, 200);

  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <TR>
    <TD>
      <DIV align=center>4</DIV>
    </TD>
    <TD>
      <DIV align=left>
        <A href="sample.asp?list=1&amp;vote=1">Juan Dela Cruz</A>
      </DIV>
    </TD>
    <TD>25</TD>
  </TR>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome. You can mark it as answer, if this really helped.